# Can I assign a variable using a function parameter?

Tags: python

Say I have a function that loads data, like so:

```
def load(filename, data):
try:
    global isFile
    with open(filename, 'rb'):
        data = pickle.load(filename)
    isFile = True
except OSError as err:
    print(error() + ': ' + err)
```

Can I assign a list, say PASSWORDS using the data parameter? Like, can I call function load(filename, PASSWORD) to assign the data to PASSWORD?

Comment: You can't _assign_ something to a parameter variable as a way of passing information _out_ of the function, if that's what you mean. But you can pass a list into a function to have stuff added into it.

Comment: Yes you can assign any type of variables as a data parameter

Answer (score 0):

xactly what you are requesting is *possible* if PASSWORD is a global variable,
and not possible if it is a local variable.

But that does not mean it should be done - if you already know the variable in the line of code you are calling the function, simply do:

```py
PASSWORD = load(filename)
def load(filename, data):
    try:
        global isFile
        with open(filename, 'rb'):
            data = pickle.load(filename)
        isFile = True
    except OSError as err:
        print(error() + ': ' + err)
        data = None  # or simply raise the error.
    return data
```

Ideally functions should not change the data objects that are passed to it, and much less change variables in the calling context - the advantage of the assignment as above is that the changing of the variable is visible and controlable in in the place that is affected.

If your word "password" is itself data, and is in a string, then more likely you should not want these to be variables - and rather having a dictionary that holds all your data - and then you can reach to the values associated with each name (such as "password") without any need to subvert the rules:

```
my_data = {}
key = "password"

...
my_data[key] = load(filename)
```

Comment: In this case, PASSWORDS is a global dictionary that either takes its data from a  save file (here) or a new file, so I want the function to directly change the dictionary. The save file, however, must include both the key (account) and value (password). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign data to mutable objects like lists when they are passed as parameter to a function.  Example included:

```
def load(filename, data):
    #load that data from filename
    passwords_from_file = ['a','b','c']
    for i in passwords_from_file:
        data.append(i)
        
data_outside_function = []
load("",data_outside_function)
print(data_outside_function)
```

this prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```